# How to attach an event handler to a dynamically created item in React native

Tags: react-native

I have created the component array using the list.push, now each item in a view has a button, now the problem is when there is a more components (50-100), when I click to that button, the app hangs for a while.

I have tried the following :

```
     if(!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.clickHandlers, index)) 
   {
    this.clickHandlers[index] = () =>  
    this.props.btnCheckOutAction(this.props.currentState.isModelOpen);
    }
    return this.clickHandlers[index];


handleItemClick(key) {
        debugger
        console.log("index::::::::::::::::::::::", key);

        if (!Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(this.clickHandlers, index)) {
            this.clickHandlers[index] = () => this.props.btnCheckOutAction(this.props.currentState.isModelOpen);
        }
        return this.clickHandlers[index];

    }
```

When I click to the button of the individual the render call the number of times the list has a component.

Comment: how do you push this into array?

Comment: componentList.push(
                <View>

                    <MyBookedTicket
                        ticketDetail={this.props.currentState.ticketArray[index]}
                        pos={position}
                    />

                </View>